# Seo url and multilanguage routing codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, seo, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with routing. I have a website in 3 languages, `AZ`, `EN`, `RU`. I have dynamic pages created from admin. So I have 3 pages domain/about, domain/en/about, domain/ru/about. Every slug is different depend on the language. So I have another domain/jobs/etc, domain/en/jobs/etc/. and it continues like this.

How I can do this routing like WordPress?

Comment: FWIW, Routing is covered in a lot of detail [In this section of the CI documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

it's symple thing using routes in codeigniter. you can write following code for `domain/en/about` url, it'll pass the language as a parameter to the function. suppose you have `index.php` controller and `about` as a function

```
    function about($language)
    {
        echo $language;
    }
```

then you've to write following line in `routes.php`

```
    $route['(:any)/about'] = 'index/about/$1';
```

now if you hit `domain/ru/about`, then output will be `ru`